# How to reset my program into default

Tags: c

Does anyone have an idea on how to reset program into default,
should i need to use loop for it?

```
int main(){

int choice = 0;
int days = 1,i;
int stocks[99];

for (;;) {

    clrscr();
    printf("Day %d\n", days);

    printf("1. harvest\n");
    printf("2. View Stocks\n");
    printf("3. Reset\n");
    printf("\nchoice: ");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1){

        clrscr();
        printf("Enter No. of rice harvested: ");
        scanf("%d", &stocks[days]);
        days++;
    }

    if (choice == 2){

        clrscr();
        printf("Day    Stocks\n");

        for (i = 1; i < days; i++){

            printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, stocks[i]);          
    }

     getch();

    }if(choice == 3){

        // reset
    }
}

}
```

for example if i reset my program the days will go back to Day 1 and the Stocks will become empty.

Comment: A simple `days = 1` is not enough?

Comment: You don't seem to be initializing the stocks array, indicating there is no default. Make an init function which loops over the array and sets the default value, whatever that might be. It should also set the default values for your other variables, like days e.g. Then call that function whenever you want to reset to your default state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If be reset, you mean that the variables should take their initial values, then just do this:

```
if(choice == 3){
  choice = 0;
  days = 1;
  // i and stocks do not have initial values, maybe nullify them
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @iCe_Star, I will upvote your question since you are new, but make sure you post your attempt as well next time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(choice == 3)
{
   days = 1;
   memset(stocks, 0x00, sizeof(stocks)/sizeof(stocks[0]));
}
```

Tip: change

```
int stocks[99];
```

to

```
int stocks[99] = {0};
```

To ensure all array fields are `0` at the start of for loop

C99 [$6.7.8/21]

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion about this int stocks[99] = {0};

Comment: @iCe_Star Take also note that day can start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the array you can use a simple for loop

```
for (i=0;i<99;i++)
    stocks[i]=0;\\ this will make sure that all values are rested to 0
```

choice and days can be set to the desired value

```
choice=0; \\ not necessary since the loop will reset and the user will enter a new value
days=1;
```